# How to send date from a textbox to listview of another form

Tags: c#, listview, textbox

Please, i need help to send data from a textbox to a listview (column quantity) of another form.

I have in form1

```
namespace officine
{
    public partial class FormClav : Form
    {
        public FormClav()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

......

```
 private void validation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // need code here
     // onclik thisend textbox1 to listview1 in formOrd
    }
```

I have a lisview1 in a second form
I fill this listview from a dabase after getting bar code.
Then I call form1 (a numeric keyboard) to change quality column.. 
So I need to send data from Textbox1 (in  `FormClav` ) to lisview1 in `FormOrdo`

```
namespace officine
{
    public partial class FormOrdo : Form
    {
.......



      private void loadproduct()
            {
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from vente";
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string[] row = { dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString()};
                        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);

                        listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
                    }
                }
                cn.Close();


            }
```

any idea pls?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a public variable in FormClav and put there the value that you need.

```
public partial class FormClav : Form
{
    public FormClav()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string yourvalue = ""

}

private void validation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 yourvalue = textbox1.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a delegate when you instantiate the second form that points to a thread-safe method in the first form that can update your listview.

Answer (score 0):

Hello to past textbox value to another form use this code:

```
  private void validation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        form2 a = new form2();
        a.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; // sets form2 as 'parent window'
        a.value = yourTextBox.Text; // sets variable 'value' in form2 equal to yourTextBox value after button is clicked
        a.Show(); //opens form2

 }
```

In form 2 generate get set value

```
  public string value { get; set; }
```

Now you can operate with `value` easily.

e.g. `listView1.Items.Add(value);`

On form load adding to listView:

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      listView1.Items.Add(value);    
    }
```

Edit:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Form2 Frm2;
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Frm2 = new Form2(this);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Frm2.Show();
      Frm2.textBox1.Text = "From Form1";
    }
  }
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    Form1 Frm1;
    public Form2(Form1 F)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Frm1 = F;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Frm1.textBox1.Text = "From Form2";
      Frm1.listView1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    }


  }
```

Comment: thanks but I don't need to open form2 again since I launch form1 from form2 ... is there a way to send value to selected line directly?

Comment: @boularouk, Sorry I thought that it was vice-versa, please see my edit. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks, but still won't work. I can change data from textbox in the same form1, but won't work from form2